# Why does java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start() starts a process by a fork()?

Tags: java

`java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start()` calls to `java.lang.ProcessImpl.forkAndExec()`, which is a native method. From what I learned in my Operating System class, a fork will basically create a clone of the process which called it. I have checked the PPID of processes created by `ProcessBuilder.start()` and confirmed that those PPIDs are equivalent to PID of current Java process.

However, `ProcessBuilder.start()` may run an arbitrarily process which share nothing with current Java process. So why does `java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start()` starts a new process by a fork()?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why does `ProcessBuilder.start()` starts a process by a `fork()`?

Because if it didn't `fork()` a child process, then the subsequent `execve()` would replace the JVM's code and data with the code and data of the new command you are running.

Why?

Because that is how the `fork()` and `execve()` system calls work.

Why?

Because:

- it allows the child process (prior to the exec) to set up the file descriptors for that the exec'd command will see, and potentially other things
- it was designed that way back in ~1970's era UNIX, and there hasn't been a strong enough case do it (significantly) differently.